# Variables and the CLI?

Tags: bash

I want the following:

```
$ DOMAIN=chron echo snippet-www.$DOMAIN.com-head.html
```

to output:

```
snippet.www.chron.com-head.html
```

but for the life of me, I can't figure out how do this except via the two commands:

```
$ export DOMAIN=chron
$ echo snippet-www.$DOMAIN.com-head.html
```

Isn't there a way to get this to work as one command?

Comment: Just curious: what benefit do you find in doing this as opposed to just `echo snippet-www.chron.com-head.html`? That is, why do you want the variable in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have stumbled upon the answer!!

**Just add a semicolon (;) after the variable assignment.**

```
$ DOMAIN=chron; echo snippet-www.$DOMAIN.com-head.html 
snippet-www.chron.com-head.html
```

Comment: ; is a new line, same as doing in two lines, but there is nothing wrong doing it in two lines.

Comment: the XXX=YYY program  syntax requires that "program" be a real program.

Comment: the problem is that the substitution is done before the variable assignment

Answer (score 1):

```
$ ( export DOMAIN=chron ; echo snippet-www.$DOMAIN.com-head.html )
```

This makes `$DOMAIN` an environment variable (which doesn't matter for this example, but might for other similar commands), and it limits its lifetime to the parentheses.

Your answer:

```
$ DOMAIN=chron; echo snippet-www.$DOMAIN.com-head.html
```

causes `$DOMAIN` to be a (non-exported) shell variable, and retains the setting for later commands.

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
DOMAIN=chron eval 'echo snippet-www.$DOMAIN.com-head.html'
```